# Is the group ring of a pro-finite group (semi)-hereditary?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

It is well-known that a group ring of a finite group is semi-simple, and since profinite-groups are projective limits of finite groups, I am thinking per chance profinite groups still possess some good properties inherited from the finite components. As I have found thus far no reference in the direction, I ask here the question: Is the group ring of a profinite group (necessarily) (semi)-hereditary?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The group ring over what field (or ring)?

Comment: Basically over the ring of integers. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: The group ring of a finite group over the integers is not semi-simple. Indeed, any module $M$ has proper submodules $nM$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. So there are no simple modules.

Comment: I know that at least it is semi-simple over $C$. So let us suppose that it is semi-simple over some field $k$, and then ask if the profinite group is (semi)-heriditary?